# Orion reentry plasma

Tags: reentry, orion-spacecraft, plasma

Below are two screen shots from the video of the Orion reentry, [Astronaut’s-Eye View of NASA’s Orion Spacecraft Re-entry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MtWzuZ6WZ8E&feature=youtu.be&t=7), and a diagram.

Is the plasma contained, or primarily within the viscous wake, as depicted in the diagram?

Is the trailing shock visible to the human eye?

[image: Orion reentry plasma 1]

[image: Orion reentry plasma 2]

[image: Reentry Flow Regions of the Apollo CM]

Comment: I don't think either shock are directly visible.  I think you are seeing emission from the heated sheath (i.e., compressed gas behind the shock).